# difference between require() and //= in application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, frontend, web-deployment

In a Rails application, inside application.js, what does the lines that start with `//= require` mean and what is the difference with a normal `require();`?

I'm new at web development, at the beginning I thought this were irrelevant as they appear as commented.

For example, this:

```
//= require cocoon
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails uses [Asset Pipeline(Sprokets)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to bundle all js and css files in one and minifies it for better performance of the page loading.

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js` called manifest file where you mention your javascript files you want to include and the order in which you want to include using

```rb
//= require
```

Similarly for css, you have `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

```rb
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

`require()` in context of ruby is to load other file in current file so that it's functionality can be reused.

`require` in context of javascritp is to load javascript modules to be used in current context/file. It's CommonJS syntaxt. This comes into picture when you use `webpacker` gem.